# Change the icon of google marker and use image from project image folder

Tags: google-maps-markers

i have a image names maker.png in project folder Image and I want to use it as google maker image how give proper path in Javascript .please help

Answer (score 6):

for the Google Map V3 in javascript you can use it in this way

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position : new google.maps.LatLng(42.344333,-76.432333),
  map      : mapObject,
  icon     : 'images/icon.png',
  title    : 'My Marker'
});
```

This will help you!

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the following URL, there are examples here

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons

You can just say 'image/marker.png'